# Ограничить величину int c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

*Например есть*

```
int a;
cin >> a;
```

*И нужно при записи ограничить величину, то есть например что бы a было больше 0 и не больше 100.


Возможно ли такое в c++ и как это сделать?*

Comment: в консоль не получится: ввод буферезируется (можно конечно заморочится и написать через небуферезированный). Почему бы не сделать проверку после ввода?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так годится?

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите число от 0 до 100",0,100);
```

Comment: В принципе подойдет, спасибо

Comment: В коде будут проблемы, если ввести число, пробел и любой текст. При том, очень хорошо они проявятся, если запросить после этого ввода другого. В своём решении я так же столкнулся с этой проблемой, но решил её в примерах 2 и 3

Для тех, кто будет искать в будущем есть альтернативы.
см. ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939747/185863