# Как запретить ввод букв?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Программа производит расчет на то, влезет ли параллелепипед в окружность, проблема в том что пользователь за место цифр допустим, может ввести букву и тогда вся программа падает. Нужно сделать защиту от дураков и запретить ввод букв. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    float L, D, a, b, c, x, y, z,PI = 3.14;
        ret:
        cout << "Длина окружности: ";
        cin >> D;
        cout << "Длина параллелепипеда: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Ширина параллелепипеда: ";
        cin >> y;
        cout << "Высота параллелепипеда: ";
        cin >> z;
    if ((D <= 0) || (x <= 0) || (y <= 0) || (z <= 0)) {
        cout << "Введены не коректные данные, введите их заново." << endl;
        goto ret;
    }
    else {
        L = D * PI; //Длина окружности
        a = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        b = sqrt(x * x + z * z);
        c = sqrt(y * y + z * z);
        if ((L > a) || (L > b) || (L > c)) {
            cout << "Влезет." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Не влезет." << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В Visual Studio есть возможность выбрать тип вводимых данных в Input который ты ставишь. Т.е. если там есть поле, в которое вводишь, его можно настроить в граф. интерфейсе. Но если нужно делать это на уровне кода, то просто перебирать символы в переменной, и если там только цифры, всё ок, но если появился любой из символов, сообщить человеку об ошибке. Во втором варианте поможет функция "sscanf()"

Comment: Посмотрите на этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/870994/195342 — а потом переделайте его под `float`. По сути, просто типы поменять...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Напишите метод для ввода данных, например так:

```
float getValue(std::string query)
{
    float value;
    std::cout << query.c_str();
    while(!(std::cin >> value))
    {
        if(std::cin.eof())
        { throw "eof"; }
        std::cin.clear(); //Сбрасываем флаг ошибки, если таковая была
        std::cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); //Игнорируем оставшиеся в потоке данные
        std::cout << "Try again: ";
    }
    return value;
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
try
{ D = getValue("Длина окружности:"); }
catch(char const *ex)
{ std::cout << ex << std::endl; }
```

Comment: Добавьте что-то типа `if (std::cin.eof()) return 0;` после ignore, а то зациклится при конце файла

Comment: `std::cin.ignore();` игнорирует ровно 1 (прописью: *один*) символ в потоке. Стоит ввести вместо числа `abc`, и ваш метод выведет стазу три "Try again: "!

Comment: @Mikhailo, Согласен с обоими замечаниями, и подправил пример. Собственно, это изначально был просто пример, а не готовое решение. И этот пример мной даже не проверялся, предполагалось, что ТС его изучит и внесет свои правки, улучшения - в зависимости от его задачи.

Comment: @avp, одно из замечаний было от вас, но система не дает отвечать сразу двум участникам.

Comment: Подправьте на константность `catch(char` **const** `*ex) { std::cout << ex << std::endl;}` Исключение `throw "eof";` не ловится.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, мое упущение, подправил.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как сделал, и вроде как оно работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int integer(const char* msg) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    string tmp;
    int value;
    while (true) {
        cout << msg;
        cin >> tmp;
        try {
            value = stoi(tmp);
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            return value;
        } catch (invalid_argument& e) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
            cout << "Вы ввели не верное значение! Введите цифры!" << endl;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    float L, D, a, b, c, x, y, z, PI = 3.14;
        ret:
        D = integer("Введите длину окружности: ");
        x = integer("Введите длину параллелепипеда: ");
        y = integer("Введите ширину параллелепипеда: ");
        z = integer("Введите высоту параллелепипеда: ");
    if ((D <= 0) || (x <= 0) || (y <= 0) || (z <= 0)) {
        cout << "Введены не коректные данные, введите их заново." << endl;
        goto ret;
    }
    else {
        L = D * PI; //Длина окружности
        a = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        b = sqrt(x * x + z * z);
        c = sqrt(y * y + z * z);
        if ((L > a) || (L > b) || (L > c)) {
            cout << "Влезет." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Не влезет." << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неужели вот такой ввод (он будет принят как правильный вашей функцией) `Введите длину окружности: 45y8` вас в самом деле устроит? Реально вы считываете и преобразуете в число только начальные цифры (в вызываемой функции `stoi(tmp)`. Наверное на самом  деле надо проверять, что следующий символ в `tmp` после числа это whitespace (пробел, табуляция. новая строка и т.п.) или в `tmp` более ничего кроме цифр нет.

Answer (score 0):

Переделанный для float ответ от Harry:

```
float inputFloat(const char * prompt, float m = -numeric_limits<float>::max(),
               float M = numeric_limits<float>::max())
{
    float N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (число с плавающей точкой от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
}
```

Для @avp:

Вот такой код:

```
int main() {
    cout << inputFloat(": ");
    }
```

Вот результат:

```
:  (число с плавающей точкой от -3.40282e+38 до 3.40282e+38): q
Неверный ввод, повторите.
:  (число с плавающей точкой от -3.40282e+38 до 3.40282e+38): a
Неверный ввод, повторите.
:  (число с плавающей точкой от -3.40282e+38 до 3.40282e+38): ^Z
Неверный ввод, повторите.
^Z
:  (число с плавающей точкой от -3.40282e+38 до 3.40282e+38): Неверный ввод, повторите.
23
:  (число с плавающей точкой от -3.40282e+38 до 3.40282e+38): 23
23
```

Comment: Что произойдет, если ввести EOF (Ctrl-D в *-nix, Ctrl-Z в Win)?

Comment: @avp Поток `cin` будет закрыт.

Comment: Да, ну? И кто же close дескриптора тут делает? Впрочем, я даже не об этом, а о том, что программа попадет в бесконечный цикл, печатающий `"Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n"`

Comment: @avp См. дополнение к ответу, что происходит на самом деле. Десятая винда, 2019-й С++.

Comment: Не знаю, как это работает в винде, а в линуксе проверил, по вводу `^D`, естественно, зацикливается. (Надо  добавить `if (std::cin.eof()) return INFINITY;` (и дополнительно `#include <cmath>`))

Comment: Я уже не повторяюсь про логическую ошибку, на которую указывал в комментарии к самоответу. Т.е. ввод типа `1q2` распознается как ошибочный только при следующем вызове функции