# Проверка на ввод нечисловых данных C++

Tags: c++, переменные, числа, проверка

Необходимо написать часть кода, который при вводе данных с клавиатуры будет пропускать только числа. Также он должен высчитывать выражения (например, если ввели 8-3, переменной присваивается 5), ну либо же чтобы он вообще не пропускал такие выражения. При введении иных данных-выводит на экран ошибку. Пользовалась стандартным if cin.fail, но при вводе выражения он ломается

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запретить ввод букв?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1324975/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2)

Answer (score -2):

Чел держи) Работает для целочисленных переменных. Если ввод неверен, то будет просить ввести, пока не введешь правильное значение.

```
void checkInt(istream& ios, int& value) {
    while (!(ios >> value) || ios.get() != '\n') // cin.fail() возвращает 1 если установлен failbit
    {
        cout << "Нужны только цифры!\n";
        ios.clear(); // сбрасывает все биты потока, тоесть поток становится "хорошим"
        ios.sync();//Удалим данные из буффера
        cin.ignore(999, '\n');
        cout << "Введите число: ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Как использовать эту функцию:  checkInt(cin, названиеПеременной);